# Почему ru.stackoverflow.com продолжает работать на территории РФ?

Tags: предложение

Многие мировые компании прекращают любое сотрудничество со страной-агрессором, закрывают свои сервисы и прекращают поставки товаров. Предлагаю закрыть `ru.stackoverflow.com` и открыть `ua.stackoverflow.com` в связи с военной агрессией России против Украины.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137176/discussion-on-question-by-mobidevices--ru-stackoverflow-com--).

Answer (score 13):

Хватит уже делить людей по национальности и гражданству. Мы - сообщество программистов, а не военных. И даже не политиков. Так давайте оставаться единым сообществом.

А что касается сайта на украинском, то его вполне можно создать, но предлагать создание сайтов надо на [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).