# Права модераторов

Tags: обсуждение, модераторский-произвол

Не считаете ли вы, что права модераторов слишком обширены. По факту каждый модератор может удалить вопрос исходя из своей суб'ективной точки зрения. Раз со управляется сообществом, почему есть индивиды, которые могут "править" больше других?

P s думаю этот вопрос уже уместен, в правильной формулировке?:D

Answer (score 12):

Как я понял, вопрос вызван удалением модератором двух ваших прошлых вопросов: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12855/373567), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12854/373567) *(вопросы удалены, видны только участникам с репутацией [10000 и выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))*.

Ознакомьтесь со справкой: [Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Немного проясню свою позицию: Да, я русский модератор, и нет, я не трогал ваши вопросы. Да, я полностью согласен с их удалением, и действия коллеги-модератора считаю правомерными по следующим причинам:

- Предложение о создании StackOverflow на украинском [уже вносилось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12024/373567) неоднократно, вы не первый.
- Предложение, мотивированное призывами к межнацрозни, разделению по расовому/религиозному/половому/иному признаку - это не то что здесь нужно.
- Мета StackOverflow на русском для публикации вашего предложения подходит точно так же как Мета на английском или испанском, то есть не подходит. Предложения на создание новых сайтов StackExchange следует вносить на сайте [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Это достаточно объективно?

Вопрос о субъективной точке зрения не стоит. Вы использовали Мету RU.SO не по назначению задавая вопросы, которые не подходят для этого сайта.

Никто за вами не охотится, никто здесь не против украинцев или участников любых других национальностей, а только за. Не стоит устраивать шум из ничего.